# HDMI Output not working on 2019 Acer Helios 300 Predator PH315-52 laptop

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

On the 2019 version of the Acer Predator helios 300 PH315-52 laptop, the HDMI output does not work at all, no video output at all. Xrandr doesnt even detect a second monitor along with gnome-settings.

I have tried Ubuntu 18 and Ubuntu 16, neither of them detect the external monitor.

The hardware is working in windows, video and everything. I have nvidia drivers installed from the Additional Drivers application on ubuntu.

I have read all other posts related to the Acer Helios HDMI issues, there is only a fix for audio which is not an issue for me.

Does anyone have an idea of why the display wouldn't show up in xrandr? Or  can anyone give me some first steps toward debugging the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Predator Helios 300 with Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660Ti, 
I had to run the following in the Terminal:

$ **sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall**

Then restart the laptop, after connecting of HDMI monitor HP 27wm is started to work.

Comment: This works but only for Ubuntu 18 and up. Not ubuntu 16

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to ubuntu 18.04, installed the latest nvidia drivers, and did sudo apt upgrade and reboot. This solved the issue